# How to iterate through object as key value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, express, javascript-objects

I'm creating a Json api in express and node. I have this ALMOST working but I can't figure out how to output the key name in this expression. Here is what I have so far...

```
for (var k in req.body) {
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(k)) {

        if (k != 'formId' && k != 'firstName' && k != 'lastName' && k != 'email' && k != 'phone' && k != 'company' && k != 'subject' && k != 'message') {
            additionalFields.push({
                k: req.body[k]
            });
        }

    }
}

console.log(additionalFields);
```

And the output is:

```
[{
    k: '$5000 - $10000'
}, {
    k: ['business cards', 'web design', 'graphicdesign']
}]
```

Which is ALMOST right, but I want the key's name instead of "k". I'm new to javascript and teaching myself as I go, so this will be a great lesson for me to remember in the future. Here is my desired result, if someone can help me get there, that would be great...

```
[{
    priceRange: '$5000 - $10000'
}, {
    servicesNeeded: ['business cards', 'web design', 'graphicdesign']
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic variable key-names you should use bracket notation. Otherwise key name is interpreted literally as `k`. Try this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[k] = req.body[k];
additionalFields.push(obj);
```

Comment: Your (now deleted) comment is confusing because it sounds like you're saying that your answer is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Thank you @Robert. I was commenting on another OP's comment, where they assumed one more incorrect version.